# For loop is ignoring my operation and returning the original array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

[][1]
I am trying to familiarize myself with arrays in JavaScript and wanted to write a function that took an array of inputs, velocities, and ran a loop through that array, each iteration using a new element from the array in the momentum equation, and then adding the resulting momentum values to a separate array.

I've tried the loop outside and inside the function, while loops and for loops, and with almost all of these approaches I am getting the original velocities array, unchanged, as the result.

I obviously don't know what the problem is but it seems like the "momentum = mass * velocities" line in the loop is being ignored (I've also tried declaring that a var). This isn't for a class so there are no constraints on how to solve this, I am just trying to get better with arrays and loops. Thanks.

```
var mass = Number(prompt('what is the mass of the object?'))
var velocities = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
i = velocities
var momentumArray = []

function findMomentum() {
    for (var i = 0; i < velocities.lenght; i++) {
        momentum = mass * velocities[i]
        push.momentumArray(momentum)
    }
    return momentumArray
}
```

Comment: `lenght` should be `length`

Comment: And what's `push.momentumArray(momentum)`? (And `i = velocities`?)

Comment: and what is i=velocities...

Comment: You should call `momentumArray.push()` to push elements to the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `i=velocities` doesn't make much sense, you misspelled length, `momentumArray.push` instead of `push.momentumArray` and add a `mass` argument in your function.

Also, no need to make your momentumArray global, and try to use let/const instead of var.

```
const mass = Number(prompt('what is the mass of the object?'))
const velocities = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

function findMomentum(mass) {
  const momentumArray = []
  for (let i = 0; i < velocities.length; i++) {
    momentum = mass * velocities[i]
    momentumArray.push(momentum)
  }
  return momentumArray
}
console.log(findMomentum(mass))
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/op32f8yk/1/

Comment: Also move the `var momentumArray = []` inside the function